# How do I access Django running on a Google Compute Engine VM from my browser?

Tags: python, django, docker, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have a Django dashboard application I wish to view from my browser. Django is running in a Docker container on one of Google's Compute Engine instances. The GCE instance is on a Google VPC, on which I've added firewall rules to open Django's port 8000. I've added my IP to Django's ALLOWED_HOSTS in settings.py. The container's logs indicate that it is running fine, yet when I access the GCE instance's IP from my browser, I am immediately unable to connect. I can ping the instance from my command line just fine. Is there something I'm missing here? Been stuck on this for a few hours now.

Note: I have the Django container running on a "Docker network" in order for Celery to communicate with a RabbitMQ container. This was recommended to me somewhere, but I am unfamiliar with Docker networks or if they are causing the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution after a bit more trial-and-error. It was not very intuitive so I'll post here in case I can help anyone else.

What fixed the issue for me was exposing the port (8000) on the command line when running the app's container:
`docker run -p 8000:8000 ...`

The reason this eluded me for so long was because I already expose the port in the Dockerfile: `EXPOSE 8000`, and when I run `docker ps` to list the ports exposed on each container, the container appeared to already be port-exposed: `8000/tcp`. However, what I didn't know is that it is supposed to look like: `0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp`.

Anyways, hope this helps someone else out.

Answer (score 1):

try to run you django app with the command

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

from the django docs:

> Note that the default IP address, 127.0.0.1, is not accessible from
>   other machines on your network. To make your development server
>   viewable to other machines on the network, use its own IP address
>   (e.g. 192.168.2.1) or 0.0.0.0 or :: (with IPv6 enabled).]
> [1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/?from=olddocs#runserver-port-or-ipaddr-port)